# Access method parameters in the the then function in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have following code in AngularJS. I am unable to access the original method parameter of 'preference' within the then function of 'updatePreferenceComplete'.

**What is the way to access the original parameter of 'preference' in the above then function?**

```
        function updatePreference(preferenceId, preference) {
        var prefId = angular.isNumber(preferenceId) ? preferenceId : 0;
        logger.info('updatePreference: fetching; preferenceId: ' + prefId);

        var route = userPreferenceConstants.endPoints.PREFERENCE_BY_ID
            .replace('{prefId}', prefId);

        return $http.put(route, preference)
            .then(updatePreferenceComplete)
            .catch(function (message) {
                exception.catcher('XHR failed for updatePreference')(message);
            });

        function updatePreferenceComplete(response) {
            //cannot access preference parameter
            logger.info('updatePreference: complete');
            return response.data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you replicate in fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, this is part of some huge code-base I have inherited, but if I can I will let you know.

Comment: Take this, I tried to do it here but it seems to work - http://jsfiddle.net/bkUEu/770/

Comment: alert does not show the value of testParam, when I run the example you have posted.

Comment: Which browser are you testing this on? I'm getting the correct `variable from func` alert.

Comment: Preference should be accessible in this context... and your variable shows up in the alert for me as well in the fiddle.

Comment: @OmriAharon, I am using latest Google Chrome browser.

Comment: @OmriAharon, So when I type something in textbox in your example and click on Send button then the alert should say what I typed. Right?

Comment: @Sunil No, I hard coded 'variable from func' into it.

Comment: @OmriAharon, then you are correct. I missed that. So the parameter is always available in the then, it seems?

Comment: @Sunil Yep, that's why it's weird that you don't see it in your code.

Comment: @OmriAharon, For some reason in my original code, when using Google Chrome I was never getting preference in the then function.

Comment: @OmriAharon, I had a http.put in my code, whereas you had a http.post in yiur exmple, but not sure if that make a difference.

Comment: @Sunil Don't think it's supposed to make a difference..

Comment: @OmriAharon, Also, in my case, things are extremely layered, which means the code I had in my question is not part of $scope directly as is the case with your example. In my case that code is part of something outside the scope/controller and its called 'UserPreferencesDataService.js'. This 'UserPreferenceDataService' is injected into the controller in my case, so any code outside scope may work differently than what you had in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    return $http.put(route, preference)
        .then(function(response) {
            updatePreferenceComplete(response, preference);
        })
        .catch(function (message) {
            exception.catcher('XHR failed for updatePreference')(message);
        });

    function updatePreferenceComplete(response, preference) {
        // now you can access preference, because it's passed as argument to the function
        logger.info('updatePreference: complete');
        return response.data;
    }
```